# Change Label.Text in EmptyDataTemplate based on TextBox.Text

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to programmatically change a label in an EmptyDataTemplate based on the text that was entered into a textbox when a button is clicked. My if (!IsPostBack) works to set the text on initial page load. However, when the Search button is clicked, the new values aren't getting assigned back properly.

Markup

```
<table runat="server">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Project #: "></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtProjectID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" />
    <br />
    <br />

        <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="BookingFormID" DataSourceID="BFListSQL">
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                <table runat="server" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;border-collapse: collapse;border-color: #999999;border-style:none;border-width:1px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>No Booking Forms found for Project # <asp:Label ID="lblProjectID" runat="server" />.</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><asp:LinkButton ID="btnNewBookingForm" runat="server" CommandName="NewInsert" Text="New Booking Form" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </EmptyDataTemplate>
....
```

Code Behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                Label lblProjectID = (Label)ListView1.Controls[0].Controls[0].FindControl("lblProjectID");
                lblProjectID.Text = "#####";
            }
        }

        protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label lblProjectID = (Label)ListView1.Controls[0].Controls[0].FindControl("lblProjectID");
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtProjectID.Text))
            {
                lblProjectID.Text = txtProjectID.Text;
            }
            else
            {
                lblProjectID.Text = "#####";
            }
        }
```

On initial Page Load, it renders with the '#####' from !IsPostBack just fine.

After I enter something in the Search textbox and click on the Search button, the rendered label.text is either null or empty as there is nothing showing where I should get either the text that was entered into the Search box or '#####'.

Would I be better off assigning a command to the button and setting the code to that instead of ButtonID_Click()?

For what it's worth, if a valid Project # is entered, the ListView table pulls up just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like a dummy. I was missing `OnCommand="btnSearch_Click"` in my buttom markup.